# Offset graphite metrics by the lowest value in current time range

Tags: monitoring, metrics, graphite, grafana

I have Grafana with Graphite metrics. I have a graph showing the `EnqueueCount` of some specific queue in ActiveMQ. The problem is that the `EnqueueCount` shows all values since the queue was created, so when I narrow down the time range in Grafana to "today so far", the graph looks like this:

[image: graph]

I would like it to show only values for current period - I would like the graph to always start at 0. In this case I would like to offset it by -2. There is an `offset` function, however it is only by constant, while I would need something like "offset by lowest value in time period".

I went through [Graphite documentation](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html), but cannot find any function which would allow me to do this.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Versions we use:

- Grafana v4.2.0 (commit: 349f3eb)
- graphite-web-0.9.12-5
- python-carbon-0.9.12-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use [nonNegativeDerivative()](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.nonNegativeDerivative) function - then you will get a **rate** of EnqueueCount change in (your metric interval, usually it is) minute. If you want to get count again - use [integral()](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.integral).

So, `integral(nonNegativeDerivative(EnqueueCount))` - but usually people looking for rate, then derivative is enough.

Comment: Using derivative to drop data from outside the selected time frame is a very smart trick :) Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed.